# Alterar cor de um <td></td> da tabela html segundo condição php

Tags: php, mysql

Em uma tabela gerada à partir de dados de um banco de dados, precisaria de alterar a para determinadas cores de um `<td></td>` se o valor do campo `ipaymentstatus` no banco de dados estiver como: completed, pending, Canceled_Reversal.

Código php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Conexão ao banco

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','paypalapi','123456');

// Seleciona o Banco de dados através da conexão acima

$conexao = mysql_select_db('paypalbd',$link); if($conexao){

$sql = "SELECT iname,iemail,ipaymentstatus,itransaction_date FROM ibn_table ORDER by itransaction_date DESC"; //Exibir últimos 10 registros, DESC

$consulta = mysql_query($sql);

echo '<table class="table">'; //table table-hover

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td><b>Cliente</b></td>';

echo '<td><b>Email</b></td>';

echo '<td><b>Status</b></td>';

echo '<td><b>Data</b></td>';

echo '</tr>';

// Armazena os dados da consulta em um array associativo

while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>'.$registro["iname"].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$registro["iemail"].'</td>';

//echo '<td>'.$registro["ipaymentstatus"].'</td>';

// Se o pagamento é aprovado seleciona cor verde

if ($registros["ipaymentstatus"] == 'Completed') {
  echo '<td style="background: #222; color: #fff;">'.$registro["ipaymentstatus"].'</td>';
 } else {
 echo '<td style="background: #ccc; color: #222;">'.$registro["ipaymentstatus"].'</td>';

 }


echo '<td>'.$registro["itransaction_date"].'</td>';

echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite.
Feito a conexão com o banco de dados e a listagem de todos os registros, chamamos a função `completPayment()` para que faça o controle das cores de background do CSS.

## Listagem com a Função mencionada:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Conexão ao banco
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','paypalapi','123456');

// Seleciona o Banco de dados através da conexão acima
$conexao = mysql_select_db('paypalbd',$link); if($conexao){
$sql = "SELECT iname,iemail,ipaymentstatus,itransaction_date FROM ibn_table ORDER by itransaction_date DESC"; //Exibir últimos 10 registros, DESC

$consulta = mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<table class="table">'; //table table-hover
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><b>Cliente</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>Email</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>Status</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>Data</b></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

// Armazena os dados da consulta em um array associativo
while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$registro["iname"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$registro["iemail"].'</td>';
    //echo '<td>'.$registro["ipaymentstatus"].'</td>';
    // Se o pagamento é aprovado seleciona cor verde
    
        $color = completePayment($registro["ipaymentstatus"]);
        echo "<td style='background: {$color}; color: #fff;'>".$registro["ipaymentstatus"]."</td>";

    echo '<td>'.$registro["itransaction_date"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

    echo '</table>';
}


function completePayment($cod){

    switch($cod){
        default:
            $color = "#FFFFFF";
            break;
            
        case 'completed':
            $color = "red";
            break;
        
        case 'two':
            $color = "black";
            break;
    }
    
    return $color;
    
}
```

Não esqueça de alterar $color dentro da função e dentro do `case` `{retorno.Tabela}` para que faça a verificação completa.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Exemplo bem didático, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo! Precisar, a disposição.